# generating a dropdown for quantity based on a number of available

Tags: php

i am creating a dropdown that will only go as high as the number that is available. for some reason, i get an unexpected foreach error, however ..not sure why. what am i doing wrong?

note that i will display the dropdown elsewhere after, that's why it's being generated this way:

```
           $range = range(1,$quantity_available);
           $qty_dropdown = '<select>'.

           foreach ($range as $qty) {
             $qty_dropdown . ='<option value="'.$qty.'">'.$qty.'</option>';
           }

           $qty_dropdown . ='</select>';
```

Comment: Mind the  $qty_dropdown = '<select>'. <-- Should be  $qty_dropdown = '<select>';

Comment: That said, which unexpected foreach error you've got?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) that's all it says.

Comment: even with the correction above by icecub.

Comment: is $range an array? have you checked it before using it?

Comment: actually, i just noticed what the error was. i did . = instead of .=